# Can't access class' height of iFrame via jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to include an Instagram-post via iFrame on my website. As the posts can have different heights (what comes from different ratios), I need to check the height of the class "Embed", that is in the body-tag of the Instagram-page.

So I include the iFrame the following way:

```
<p class="embedded-iframe">
 <iframe class="instagram-embed" id="iframe-1" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/COvuizXoHPD/embed/captioned/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" data-iframe-id="1">
 </iframe>
</p>
```

Without any further CSS, the iFrame gets an width of 300px and a height of 150px.

Now in the iFrame's body-tag, there is a div with the class "Embed", and this class has the height I need for styling the iFrame.
So I tried to get the height of this class, but it won't work. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("iframe").load(function(){

        console.log("iFrame loaded");

        var test = $("iframe").contents().find(".Embed").height();

        console.log(test);

    });

});
```

The first log-entry is written correctly into the console, but then value of `var test` is *null*.
I also tried it with different classes, but everytime the same problem.

Comment: You can not access the content of a 3rd party iframe

Answer (score 0):

try used `find("html").html()` for get content

example:

```
var htmlIframe=$('#iframe-1').contents().find("html").html();
htmlIframe.find(".Embed").height();
```

Comment: This brings an error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: htmlIFrame is undefined` in Firefox respectively `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` in Chrome